# Error while trying to install smart contract using npm run cc:start -- supplychain

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hurley

I am new to blockchain and we are using hyperledger fabric to run it. 
The project instructions read:

1. `npm i` //to install dependencies
2. `npm run env:restart` //Create a new development blockchain network  - From the root of your project
3. `npm run cc:start -- supplychain` //Install your smart contract
   followed by command(s) to create a record in the ledger.

The first two steps are running, i.e. my network is getting set up successfully.

Step no. 3 is failing with the following error.

I have installed hurl as well. Have previously tried clearing cache as well but that did not ease things for me either.

Please help, I don't understand this error and which are the defining lines/aspects of it (might help to search). I have tried bits and parts separately but at this point an overall understanding would go a long way to help.

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: npm: not found
"
[hurley] - Found error while running script!
(node:22518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Errors found in script, stopping execution
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/@worldsibu/hurley/dist/utils/sysWrapper.js:116:27)
    at step (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:139:27)
    at Object.next (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:120:57)
    at /home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:109:16)
    at Object.execContent (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/@worldsibu/hurley/dist/utils/sysWrapper.js:112:24)
    at InstallChaincodeShGenerator.BaseGenerator.run (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/@worldsibu/hurley/dist/generators/base.js:18:40)
    at ChaincodeGenerator.install (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/@worldsibu/hurley/dist/generators/chaincodegenerator.js:59:35)
    at ChaincodeCLI.<anonymous> (/home/avantika/Documents/major-blockchain/pharma-chain/node_modules/@worldsibu/hurley/dist/cli.js:351:55)
(node:22518) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:22518) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```